# Can I resize the texture pattern that applied via Illustrator graphic styles?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, texture, patterns

Can I resize the texture pattern that applied via Illustrator graphic styles? And if not, is there any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you could give a bit more information or even link a screenshot. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, but it depends on the graphic style you're trying to scale.

Graphic Styles are just a collection of filters. You can edit the filters by expanding the Fill of the object the style is applied to (in the `Appearance` pane):

[image: RGB Cobblestone]

To scale this Graphic Style, we can click on the `Stained Glass` effect and edit the cell size:

[image: Stained Glass Cell Size]

This will increase the size of the "stones" in the Graphic Style:

[image: Scaled Graphic Style]

It will be a different setting to tweak for each Graphic Style since they are all different, but this should put you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks, John. But what about the RGB image that comes with the graphic style?

Comment: Which part, the gradient?